# Cannot download m3u8 using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to download a mp4 from m3u8 link using ffmpeg command.

```
ffmpeg -i https://hls.mediacdn.vn/vtv/2019/4/7/0704sao-mai-1554652229269816114782-af6d9.mp4/master.m3u8 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output1.mp4
```

But an error occurred when loading first segment

```
https://hls.mediacdn.vn/vtv/2019/4/7/0704sao-mai-1554652229269816114782-af6d9.mp4/720/seg-1-v1-a1.ts?v=664e3521
```

```
https://hls.mediacdn.vn/vtv/2019/4/7/0704sao-mai-1554652229269816114782-af6d9.mp4/master.m3u8: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Someone helps me to solve my problem. Thanks!

Full command

```
ffmpeg -i https://hls.mediacdn.vn/vtv/2019/4/7/0704sao-mai-1554652229269816114782-af6d9.mp4/master.m3u8 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output2.mp4ffmpeg version 4.1.1-0york1~16.04 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='0york1~16.04' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[hls,applehttp @ 0x56551c942500] Opening 'https://hls.mediacdn.vn/vtv/2019/4/7/0704sao-mai-1554652229269816114782-af6d9.mp4/720.m3u8?v=664e3521' for reading
[https @ 0x56551cd51280] Opening 'https://hls.mediacdn.vn/vtv/2019/4/7/0704sao-mai-1554652229269816114782-af6d9.mp4/480.m3u8?v=3f40a361' for reading
[https @ 0x56551cd51280] Opening 'https://hls.mediacdn.vn/vtv/2019/4/7/0704sao-mai-1554652229269816114782-af6d9.mp4/360.m3u8?v=aefcb682' for reading
[https @ 0x56551cd51280] Opening 'https://hls.mediacdn.vn/vtv/2019/4/7/0704sao-mai-1554652229269816114782-af6d9.mp4/240.m3u8?v=bda86a2a' for reading
[https @ 0x56551cd51280] Opening 'https://hls.mediacdn.vn/vtv/2019/4/7/0704sao-mai-1554652229269816114782-af6d9.mp4/144.m3u8?v=431e8038' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 0x56551c942500] Opening 'https://kms.sohatv.vn/drm/55ceb3f8-4675-454a-bfc8-96cb04bbae8f.key' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 0x56551c942500] Opening 'crypto+https://hls.mediacdn.vn/vtv/2019/4/7/0704sao-mai-1554652229269816114782-af6d9.mp4/720/seg-1-v1-a1.ts?v=664e3521' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 0x56551c942500] Error when loading first segment 'https://hls.mediacdn.vn/vtv/2019/4/7/0704sao-mai-1554652229269816114782-af6d9.mp4/720/seg-1-v1-a1.ts?v=664e3521'
https://hls.mediacdn.vn/vtv/2019/4/7/0704sao-mai-1554652229269816114782-af6d9.mp4/master.m3u8: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: full command line and console output please...

Comment: @rogerdpack I updated my question.

Comment: It might be useful to include the contents of of the m3u8 file (It's just text).  As already pointed out, it might be related to decrypting the file and m3u8 contents might give some details about that.

Answer (score 5):

The stream is encrypted, and the key is encoded in an obfuscated format. ffmepg will not be able to decrypt the stream.